# Forcing RollingFileAppender with BufferedIO to push logs even if the buffer is not full

Tags: tomcat, log4j

I am using log4j for logging in my application. I have specifically chosen the RollingFileAppender with the following settings.

```
log4j.appender.file.immediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.file.bufferedIO=true
```

Where I chose to use the default buffer size which is 8KB.

This works fine when the logs are consistenly pushed. Although it writes into the file 8KB at a time. So I need to wait for the logs. I am ok with it.

The issue comes in when I just restart the tomcat server and by some reason it stops after a while(the buffer is still not full to 8KB) so all the logs are getting lost as the appender doesn't write it into the file and I am not able to figure out the cause for server startup failure.

Is there any solution for the same?

Thanks